# Updating values based on 3 table join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables `orders`, `customer_old` and `customer_new`.

- The `orders` table contains the `old_user_login` and associated order number.
- The `customer_old` table contains the information on
  customer, namely `old_user_login` and `user_fullname`.
- The `customer_new` table contains `new_user_login` and `user_fullname`.

The idea is to replace the `old_user_login` with `new_user_login` for all the rows in the `orders` table, and the only thing that matches is the `user_fullname` in the two customer tables. The old customer table will effectively be made redundant and deleted after this operation is done.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how that could be done:

```
--demo setup
Declare @Orders table (OrderNumber int, UserLogin varchar(20))
Declare @CustomerOld table (UserLogin varchar(20), UserFullName varchar(30))
Declare @CustomerNew table (UserLogin varchar(20), UserFullName varchar(30))

insert into @Orders (OrderNumber,UserLogin) values(1,'SillySam')
insert into @CustomerOld(UserLogin,UserFullName) values('SillySam','Sam Snyder')
insert into @CustomerNew(UserLogin,UserFullName) values('SillySamUpdated','Sam Snyder')

--solution
UPDATE o
SET o.UserLogin = cn.UserLogin  --update orders.UserLogin with value retrieved from CustomerNew
FROM @Orders o
JOIN @CustomerOld co        --join CustomerOld to Orders using UserLogin
    ON co.UserLogin = o.UserLogin
JOIN @CustomerNew cn        --join CustomerNew to CustomerOld using UserFullName from both tables
    ON cn.UserFullName = co.UserFullName

--verify
select * from @Orders
```

---

```
OrderNumber UserLogin
1           SillySamUpdated
```

Comment: thank you, if I wanted to test this on a single user how would I construct the WHERE clause, and would I base this on the old login, new login, or the full name?

Comment: @SimStil - `where co.UserLogin = 'OldLogin'` or `where o.UserLogin = '???'`

Comment: @SimStil - You can always run the update (and select) inside a transaction and verify before committing it.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!